# C++ arrow type yields lvalue

Tags: c++, decltype, lvalue, rvalue

According to the C++ Primer, C++ arrow operator yields an lvalue. Additionally  `decltype`  of an expression which yields an lvalue will result in a reference type. So why the following decltype does **not** result in a reference type.

```
struct MyStruct {
   string name
};
MyStruct s;
s.name = "aname";
MyStruct* p = &s;
decltype (p -> name) str = s.name; //type of str will be string and not &string although p -> name yields an lvalue
```

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) (which is from *§7.1.6.2/4 [dcl.type.simple]*):

> If the argument is an unparenthesized id-expression or an **unparenthesized class member access**, then decltype yields the type of the entity named by this expression.

`p->name` falls in the above case, so the type of `decltype(p->name)` is the type of `p->name` which is `std::string` not `std::string&`.

On the other hand, `decltype((p->name))` is `std::string&` because `(p->name)` is an lvalue expression.

Answer (score 9):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)

> If the argument is an unparenthesized id-expression or an **unparenthesized class member access, then decltype yields the type of the entity named by this expression.** If there is no such entity, or if the argument names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed.

This is the case in your example, so it will return the underlying type of the member, which is a `std::string`.

If you want, you can add parenthesis so that `decltype` results in a reference:

```
//'str' is a std::string&
decltype((p->name)) str = s.name;
```